# Converting List[LIst[objects]] to List[Object] in scala

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala, I need to convert a `List[List[(String, Int)]]` into a  `List[(String, Int, Int)]`:

My  original List contains, for example, `[(x, 20), (y,20)], [(x, 30), (y,40)]`. The result should be `[(x , 20, 30), (y, 20, 40)]`, i.e. list of tuples.

I tried following code:

```
data.reduce {(object1, object2) =>
val newObject = object2.find(matter => matter.key == object1.key)
new model(object1.x, object1.value, newObject.value)
}
```

but it is throwing an error that reduce has to return same type.

Comment: Are you certain that your `List[List[Model]]` will always contain exactly 2 lists?

Comment: No Jasper it contails n no of Items.

Comment: `[(x, 20), (y,20)]` is not a `List[List[Tuple2]]`, it is a `List[Tuple2]`

Comment: @kittu But then the resulting "tuple" will also contain n+1 items, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the result to have the type `List[(String, Int, Int)]`, which implies that you assume each "key" (letter, e.g. `x`) has *exactly* two matching tuples (otherwise the resulting List might have items that are not 3-Tuples).

If that's the case:

```
val data = List(List(("x", 20), ("y",20)), List(("x", 30), ("y",40)))

val result: List[(String, Int, Int)] = data
  .flatten // flatten to get a list of tuples
  .groupBy(_._1) // group by tuple's first element
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2)) // get rid of "key" in value list
  .map { case (k, List(i1, i2)) => (k, i1, i2) }.toList // ASSUMEs each key has exactly two entries, creates 3-Tuples

println(result) // List((y,20,40), (x,20,30))
```

Otherwise - if the tuples in the result aren't guaranteed to all have the same number of elements (i.e. not all "keys" will have exactly two "values"), then I'd strongly suggest to stay with `Lists`, which you be achieved by:

```
val data = List(List(("x", 20), ("y",20)), List(("x", 30), ("y",40)), List(("x", 50)))

val result: List[List[Any]] = data
  .flatten // flatten to get a list of tuples
  .groupBy(_._1) // group by tuple's first element
  .map { case (k, l) => k :: l.map(_._2) }.toList // prepend key to list of values


println(result) // List(List(y, 20, 40), List(x, 20, 30, 50))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an exact answer to your (not 100 percent consistent) question. 
I think you are looking for a Map[String, List[Int]].

```
val res = data.flatten.distinct.groupBy(_._1).map(a => a._1 -> a._2.map(_._2))

println(res)  // Map(y -> List(20, 40), x -> List(20, 30))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val ls1 = List(('x', 20), ('y',20))
val ls2 = List(('x', 30), ('y',40))
val ls = List(ls1,ls2)

println(ls.flatMap(x => x).groupBy(x => x._1).map{case(x,y) => (x,y.map(z => z._2)) }.toList)
```